# forecast.HoltWinters : function not found error message remote machine but same code run in another machine

Tags: r, machine-learning, analytics, forecasting

I am using R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) in remote machine and  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) n my desktop 
In the remote machine, it's throwing me an error by saying forecast.HoltWinters not found

I have kept exact replica of all inputs required in both machine

I have cross checked all the required packages are installed

I am not sure where I am doing wrong can some one help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you loaded the library? `library(forecast)`.

Comment: Yes I have loaded the  library(forecast)

Comment: Use `forecast()` instead of `forecast.HoltWinters()`

Comment: Thank you, Rob Hyndman but this is sorted out by changing into forecast instead of a forecast.Holwinter() but "PSF" function is not found it's there in 3.2.2 forecast package but not in 3.4.1  Other related info  in 3.4.1 if I run the ls("package: forecast") I will get close 99 functionality I will get it but if I run the same thing in 3.2.2  I will get close to 156 functionalities  How to make compatible across all the versions

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to use `forecast:::forecast.HoltWinters` (triple colons).